# mvn compile works, but in IntelliJ IDEA compile fails: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

Development environment: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1, Maven 3.6.3, Spring Boot 2.4.0,

below sample code. File `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

File `TestController.java`

```java
package com.example.demo2;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

}
```

Command `mvn compile` works.

But execute IntelliJ IDEA memnu `Build``Recompile` , file 'TestController.java' fails with below error

```
Error:(3, 47) java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
```

I tried removing file `*.iml` , `*.idea` but the problem cannot resolve.

I tried `mvn clean` the problem cannot resolve.

I changed Spring Boot from `2.4.0` to `1.5.9.RELEASE`, it works. But why I used version `2.4.0` it did not work?

**Update:**

Sample project and idea.log at https://pan.baidu.com/s/1EeP7HO_XKHfoVNhcaAbM8w . Extract code: 1tq6

Comment: Did you try [reloading Maven dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_import_dependency)? If after this action it still did not work - it could be a bug. Can you provide a sample project and idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file?

Comment: Sure, each time pom.xml changed, I click Load Maven Changes button. And I just tried Reimport All Maven Projects of Maven tool window, it didn't help. Sample project and idea.log at https://pan.baidu.com/s/1EeP7HO_XKHfoVNhcaAbM8w . Extract code: 1tq6

Comment: Try version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: I can not download from mentioned resource, can yo upload it somewhere else? Please  try to upload at https://uploads.services.jetbrains.com or any other file sharing service. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrey Thank you for help, Here is the jetbrains Upload id: 2020_12_04_5KcwNhoVFDzp2s33 (file: demo2.zip)

Comment: Do you have problem only with this porject? Try with these plugins disabled: `Loaded custom plugins: PlantUML integration (2.25.2), Lombok (0.30-2020.1), Alibaba Java Coding Guidelines (2.1.0), Kotlin (1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-3) `

Comment: Also try changing the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Store generated project files externally** option.

Comment: @Andrey Thank you again. This problem happens not only with this project, but with all projects with Spring Boot 2.4.0, and disappears with Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE. Disabling those four plugins (then restart IDEA), and/or turn on/off Store generated project files externally, then rebuild project, all get the same error as before.

Comment: Very strange that command line Maven works but IDE's build does not. Do try the tgings mentioned above. File an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the screenshots, the project and idea.log attached after IDE restart and reproducing.

Comment: Thanks, issue fired: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259529

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem? I tried removing repository from m2  and doing a complete  mvn clean install, I also tried invalidating cache and restarted intellij. The problem came after I upgraded spring boot version from 2.3.9-Snapshot to 2.4.12. IntelliJ has decided NOT to work at all. Currently I am working on 
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-211.7628.21, built on June 30, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1341.60 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2016M
Cores: 8

Comment: @Klose I didn't get a solution to Spring Boot 2.4.0, but work this problem around by using a Spring Boot version other than 2.4.0.

Comment: This is absolutely weird for intelliJ not to support a particular version. Is it something to do with community edition or the ultimate version also has the same issue? I had certain dependencies to add for which I have to upgrade spring version to 2.4.12 and this IDE went crazy.

Comment: It happened with ultimate version when I got this issue. Sorry I have no further clues

Answer (score 2):

Checking the Maven settings for

```
Maven home path
```

and changing its value to `Bundled (Maven 3)` solved the issue!
Somehow it was set to <s>Use maven wrapper</s>.
[image]